# how to know whether stanford dependency parser performs tokenization based on rule-based methods or probabilistic theory?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am confused whether stanford dependency parser performs tokenization of sentences and words based on probabilistic theory or rule-based methods?? and I want to know what is dependency grammar and dependency parsing
please helpp!!!
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tokenization is entirely rule-based. If you're curious, you can take at the (very lengthy) [tokenizer definition for English](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBLexer.flex).

There is a short introduction to dependency parsing on [this Stanford page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml), with some links to relevant papers as well.